# general solution for equations of the form $x^k+a/x=b$.

Tags: systems-of-equations, algebraic-curves, nonlinear-system

I tried with Mathematica and there is a formula for solving $x^k+a/x=b$ when $k=1,2,3$. Is there a general way of solving this when $k>1, a>0, b>0$?

Comment: Not with an explicit formula; this equation is equivalent to $x^{k+1}-bx+a=0$ and when $k\geq 4$ the resulting polynomial might be unsolvable (in the Galois sense). In the quintic case in particular (i.e., $k=4$) it's known that any 5th-degree polynomial can be reduced to this form. Contrariwise, there are solutions available via hypergeometric functions, which are arguably the next best thing to a closed-form.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki would you please elaborate on solutions via hypergeometric functions? thanks!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html (found by literally just searching 'quintic equation hypergeometric') talks about it a bit.